# Time Series chart using external csv data with highcharts

Tags: json, csv, highcharts, time-series, timeserieschart

I am trying to create a Time Series chart with data from an external .csv file.
I went through the demo available on http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series, which uses a JSON file to load the data.

Data in my CSV looks like this

```
9/30/2015 18:39,21331.88672
9/30/2015 18:38,21331.86328
9/30/2015 18:37,21331.85156
9/30/2015 18:36,21331.83594
9/30/2015 18:35,21331.82031
9/30/2015 18:34,21331.80078
9/30/2015 18:33,21331.78516
9/30/2015 18:32,21331.76953
```

I tried to convert this into a JSON format and load it into the code but the chart does not render. Only the axis loads as follows.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HppK.png)

Kindly help me with the chart.

Comment: Including your code would be helpful. We can only guess as to what the problem is without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Recreate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net

Comment: @HalvorStrand
I tried to implement and have come up with a line chart with the same data and it works, check the result. 
https://jsfiddle.net/shoghi07/ddnLdyrd/

Comment: So it works in jsFiddle but not in your app?  Could you edit your original question with your code from app?

Comment: @PawełFus, the fiddle works fine in the app.
Thank you for your efforts! :)